# Como passar um dicionário para a função range()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu estava vendo a documentação (docstring) da função range e me deparei com o seguinte:

```py
Init signature: range(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:     
range(stop) -> range object
range(start, stop[, step]) -> range object
```

Meu entendimento é que a função `range()` recebe tanto argumentos posicionais (uma tupla ou lista) quanto argumentos com palavra-chave (dicionário).

Testando, eu consegui fazer o seguinte:

```py
# passando argumentos da forma padrão:
for i in range(0, 10, 1):
    print(i)
```

Retorna a sequencia de 1 a 10, com passo 1.

```py
# passando argumentos como uma lista:
for i in range(*[1, 10, 2]):
    print(i)
```

Utilizando o `*` como indicador de "desempacotamento", o range resolve e devolve um iterável com: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9.

E se eu quisesse passar um dicionário, como abaixo?

```py
for i in range(**{'start':0, 'stop':100, 'step':10}):
    print(i)
```

Ao executar o código acima eu tomo um erro:

> TypeError: range() takes no keyword argumentsrangeRange

É um erro no docstring, ou não tem mesmo uma forma de passar `**kwargs` para o range?

---

EDIT: versão e docstring
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Em qual versão de Python você viu isso? Até onde sei isso não é possível. Em tempo na versão 3.8.1 a docstring é diferente

Comment: Não tem como fazer, mas pessoas ociosas sempre inventam suas gambiarras `for i in range(*{'start':0, 'stop':100, 'step':10}.values()): print(i)`

Comment: @Augusto Vasques, nesse caso, o que é passado para o range é uma tupla, gerada a partir do dicionário. Existe garantia que os valores trazidos pelo método ```dict.values()```  estarão sempre na ordem que foram declarados?

Comment: *Alterado na versão 3.7: Ordem do dicionário é garantida conforme a ordem de inserção. Este comportamento era um detalhe de implementação do CPython a partir da versão 3.6.* Ref: https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict , mas não deixa de ser uma gambiarra pois é código verboso para uma operação simples.

Comment: @PauloMarques, a versão que vi esse docstring foi na 3.9.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso acontece porque a função `range` não é implementada diretamente no Python, mas sim em C. Nesse caso, a função em C foi desenvolvida de modo a aceitar somente os argumentos na forma posicional.

Embora, no caso do `range`, seja mostrado pela documentação os nomes de argumento `start`, `stop` e `step`, eles não podem ser passados através da forma nomeada por conta da referida limitação.

Da [referência da linguagem](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> **CPython implementation detail:** An implementation may provide built-in functions whose positional parameters do not have names, even if they are ‘named’ for the purpose of documentation, and which therefore cannot be supplied by keyword. In CPython, this is the case for functions implemented in C that use [`PyArg_ParseTuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#c.PyArg_ParseTuple) to parse their arguments.

---

> Esta resposta foi baseada [nesta pergunta (e respostas)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28926657/7445826) do SOen.

Comment: Isso - além disso, note que a "/" na assinatura foi incluida no Python 3.8 (ou 3.7 - não lembro) para permitir parametros "positional only" em Python puro  - mas por conta de qual argumento vira qual parametro mudar com o número de argumentos no range, a docstring não respeita essa convenção

Comment: Outra coisa uqe vale a pena mencionar é que range, assim como outros builtins como "int" e "str", apesar de "parecer" uma função, é uma classe - a sintaxe de Python faz com que possamos usar esses chamáveis ("callable" em inglês) sem nos preocuparmos se são classes ou funções.